# Yii and bugs with saving CActiveModel

Tags: php, yii

These codes in public funtion in model class. Trying fix this problem some hours. I have slept and now still dont know :)

```
  $meetingID = 123;
    1)code1
    $meeting = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
    $meeting->mID7 = 123;  // work (real saving in table)
    $meeting->save(true);  // work (real saving in table)

    2)code2 = just add '2'(or something else) to code1
    $meeting2 = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
    $meeting2->mID7 = 123;  // DONT work (dont save in table)
    $meeting2->save(true);  // DONT work (but return 1!!!) (dont save in table)

    3)code2 + code1 = work version of 'broken' code :D
    $meeting2 = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
    $meeting2->mID7 = 123;  // work!!! (real saving in table)
    $meeting2->save(true);  // work!!! (real saving in table)

    $meeting = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
    $meeting->mID8 = 123;   // work (real saving in table)
    $meeting->save(true);   // work (real saving in table)
```

In macro code like this:

```
$meetingID = 123;
$meeting = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
if ($meeting) {

...this codes...

}
```

**I find out that this start name of CActiveModel bugging all code after:**

```
$meetingID = 123;
$meeting12345 = Meeting::model()->findByPk( $meetingID );
if ($meeting12345 ) {
    ...this codes...
}
```

And now code1 and code2 DONT WORK/SAVE. ONLY code with variable model name = **meeting12345** will be work if key to find is the same(**$meetingID**).

Comment: What did you mean by adding text in code snippet or joining two code snippets? Could you please make it clear?

Comment: 3) = code1 after code2 in my public function in Meeting.php file (i just ctrl+c and ctrl+v it here)

Comment: can you provide some more detail, what you exactly want to do and what error you are getting?

Comment: i want working code2 start work

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are writing code seem you are trying to update with the same value the same record and then you can't see any change.

If you want see the update effect change some value, otherwise if you want a new record create the new one with

```
 $myNewMeeting = new Meeting;
```

add the value you need

```
 $myNewMeeting->myField1 = 'value field1';
 ...
 $myNewMeeting_>Save();
```